# I've been waiting vs I was waiting

Tags: grammaticality

If “I have been waiting for someone for 2 hours", it seems to me that the action started in the past and is still on or just finished (at the moment of speaking)

But if I want it to show in the past, **what should I use**?
"I was waiting for someone for 2 hours" or "I have been waiting"?

Also, I know if we want to note the fact, not the duration, it's fine to put past simple, isn't it?

Could you please make it clear for me?

Comment: You "was waiting". The action happened in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"was waiting" reflects that the action finished in the past, usually you provide the reference to the past.

"have been waiting", as you've described, should point out that the action has relevance to the present.

"was waiting" is the one you are looking for and, if constructed correctly, you may use "had been waiting"
ex. I had been waiting for 2 hours by the time my friend came.